# how to get the spring config xml from a jar in web.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

read jar's spring config xml in web.xml

i create a maven  multi-module maven project .include DAO module .in this module i use hibernate and spring .i install it . and then i create a independent maven web project .and i use this jar. i don't want to use classpath:xxx.xml.because i want the other people to use my jar without to knew my xml's name ,because that jar include many xml. i want to know how to solve this problem. i'm try to write a new spring listener? or other ways .thanks .

Comment: I suggest that you will rephrase and refine your question. I found it hard to understand. Anyway I tried to answer, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want your jar to 100% be self-containing.
It will be hard to achieve that. 
The user of your project will need some starting point to bootstrap the configuration.
You will need to provide some documentation.
Anyway I can suggest the following.

stick to annotation as match as possible in your DAOs, user @Repository @Autowire etc.This way you will only need to ask the users of your jar add the following to their application context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.dao.package"/>
```

Use the default persistence.xml naming standard and placed your persistence.xml under the META-INF directory. Do not specify persistence unit name. 
If the user will define EntityManagerFactory without a persistenceUnitName it will load your configuration. 
The user will have to use emf jpaVendorAdapter and datasource property to define is custom database configuration
for example:

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>
```

As you can see you can get close to self-containing jar when sticking to spring conventions. Anyway you will need to give some hints to your jar user